What is the right view/attitude towards dukkha?
In the conventional sense, views on dukkha (stress/hardships/difficulties/suffering) are rather mixed. We have the saying, “No pain, no gain” that implies that suffering is needed to make progress. There is also the saying, “Whatever doesn’t kill you, makes you stronger”, again implying how difficult experiences make a person more resilient. Yet, it is known today many diseases are stress-related.
I have friends/acquaintances who suffered from diseases which I strongly suspect is a result of their stressful lifestyles. What is strange from my observations is that most of the time, they are either not aware or simply feel that everything is normal. I suspect that over the years and decades even though the stress had reached chronic level, their mind had grown used to it even though their bodies did not. In fact, one of them appeared nonchalant when I implied that there might be a link between her illness and stress. Sometimes, I wish doctors are just as good at curing the mind as they are with the body.

How should lay Buddhists view and make use of dukkha such that it is helpful not only spiritually but also allow them to make meaningful progress in the world?
Is there a way to strike a balance with stress in our personal and professional lives?
What advice would you give to non-Buddhist friends who are suffering from chronic stress?


Those with stress do not sleep at ease.

AN3.35:1.5: “Sir, I trust the Buddha slept well?”
AN3.35:1.6: “Yes, prince, I slept well.
AN3.35:1.7: I am one of those who sleep at ease in the world.”

Yet, knowing that some people do not sleep well, the Buddha did not actively seek out sleepless people to cure them. Instead, he simply answered those who sought his help. He only answered those who saw a problem and sought a solution:

AN3.35:2.1: “The winter nights are cold, sir, and it’s the week of mid-winter, when the snow falls. Rough is the ground trampled under the cows’ hooves, and thin is the mat of leaves. The leaves are sparse on the trees, the ocher robes are cold, and cold blows the north wind.
AN3.35:2.2: And yet the Buddha says,
AN3.35:2.3: ‘Yes, prince, I slept well.
AN3.35:2.4: I am one of those who sleep at ease in the world.’”
AN3.35:3.1: “Well then, prince, I’ll ask you about this in return, and you can answer as you like.

The Buddha then explains why he sleeps at ease...(click links above for details).
Greed, hate, and delusion disturb our rest. So perhaps one answer to your questions might be that the right view of dukkha is that it disturbs our rest.

these ascetics will surely freeze to death

@blue_eggo In the extreme, indeed, however, I've noticed that I sleep better on the floor than on a soft plushy bed. That was surprising to me. And in the mountains I sleep fine on a thin insulating pad on the ground.

The modern (Westernized) world is ruled by asura-demons; causing the multitude to conform to Mara's asura rulers as hungry ghosts, animals & hell beings.
Those with Dhamma find the method to live, as explained in the Maha-mangala Sutta:

Not to associate with the foolish.

To honor those worthy of honor (rather than honor Mara's asuras).

To reside in a suitable locality (away from Mara's baits; where the costs of living are affordable).

Engaged in peaceful occupations (which do not compromise ethics).

To cease and abstain from evil.

To abstain from intoxicating drinks.

Contentment (with simple living).

Timely hearing of the Dhamma, the teaching of the Buddha (not polluted by alien religions & ideologies).

Comprehension of the Noble Truths (which explain various cravings are the cause of dukkha).



Your view about the world being ruled by asura-demons is quite radical. But looking at the state of the world it is hard to refute either, sigh.

Sorry but it’s not radical. Note: per the link asura are a class of people

Views on dukkha aren't 'mixed'; the concept of dukkha is misunderstood.
Dukkha is a state where there's a dissonance between the way we feel the world should be, and the way we perceive the world is. There are a lot of ways this state can arise:

Sometimes things are unpleasant, and we'd like them to be more so
Sometimes our feelings lead us astray, when there's nothing actually
wrong
Sometimes we perceive things wrongly, and it kicks up feelings
Sometimes we perceive the world wrongly and are happy with our
misperceptions, then get blindsided when our wrong perceptions lead
to unexpected results

It takes discrimination to see that this dissonance is actually a conflict between our feelings and our perceptions, and not something intrinsic to the world. The issue of 'pain' is a good example. Pain is an occasional feature of the world; a condition of the body alerting us to some physical issue. But when we feel that the pain we perceive is wrong and wish that we weren't perceiving it at all, then dissonance (dukkha) arises. There's no metaphysical issue to feeling pain; it is what it is. But there is a metaphysical issue in reifying pain into a mental state of suffering, so that our mental attitudes about it persist and magnify over and beyond the pain itself. Sometimes pain and hardship can make us stronger; sometimes people seek them out for exactly that purpose. But suffering makes us weaker, because we invest too much energy in our mis-feelings or misperceptions.
The modern world is finely tuned to generate the maximum amount of dukkha without actually (on average) breaking people down. No matter which way we turn, we will find someone telling us that we are not quite good enough, not quite good-looking  enough, not quite successful enough, not quite happy enough… Duhkka motivates product sales, job performance, dating activity, TikTok and Insta streams, Reality TV, political campaigns… It's a Hungry Ghost mentality, and if we fall prey to it it can create a lot of stress and misery, because nothing will ever seem good enough. But the operative word  is 'enough'. When people start to realize that they have 'enough' just as it is, this misery reduces from tanhā (a deep craving or primal-seeming need) to mere duhkka (dissonance), and then from dukkha to a level of peace. Getting 'a bit more' becomes a nicety, not a necessity, and things in our heads untangle and unwind. It is not an easy realization, though…

When is enough enough? Perhaps, it is not just desire but also fear that causes so much angst and misery.

"But when we feel that the pain we perceive is wrong and wish that we weren't perceiving it at all," - this is very confusing to me. existential threats are not wrong.  dreading going to my job is not wrong. yes, it takes away from the glory of present moment, but that's the situation we have brought upon ourselves

@blue_eggo: I'm not sure what's confusing you. I mean, if we fall in a deep hole and twist an ankle, that's what happened. Our eyes tell us we fell in a hole; the pain tells us we twisted an ankle. Everything else is just mental stuff.  Do we sit down and whine? Rage about whoever dug the hole? Berate ourselves for not seeing it? An existential threat is a threat to a future that doesn't yet exist, so not really existential at all… We can sit in the hole or climb out of it, as we like.  but there's no sense sitting in the hole and wishing it were otherwise.

I think it might be the fight-or-flight mentality and today is football Sunday btw

@blue_eggo: Is that American football, Australian football, or football of the civilized world?

nothing uncivilized about color - "It perceives blue, it perceives yellow, it perceives red, it perceives white."

I would advise practicing one of the Brahmaviharas which is called Mudita. Mudita means sympathetic JOY.
Rejoice for what you have and what small or big things you can accomplish.
Rejoice for what others have and what others can accomplish.
Rejoice for what your enemies have and what they can accomplish.
Rejoice for the True knowledge which Buddha has given.
Rejoice for the developing the most generous heart.
Rejoice for developing most compassionate heart.
Rejoice for developing most friendly attitude towards all living beings.
Rejoice for developing most equanimous attitude towards all living beings.
Rejoice for promising to never return to any kind existence ever.
My advice is Meditate on Mudita. This will cure all the stress and will make you happy under all circumstances.
I personally do not divide between personal and professional life. This will create bipolar disorder and will become a hindrance in developing the required attitude to attain liberation.

That it sucks, it's caused by desire, and there's a way out, the Eightfold Path.

Making use of it would mean being motivated to find the cure. The Teachings say "stress results either in bewilderment or in search" (AN 6.63). Old age, sickness and death are the reason the Buddha is said to have left home, to find the solution.
 
One teacher said they have a saying that "samsara is kind", in that it'll always remind you what it really is. You can be lulled into complacency when life seems to be going good, like in the simile of the burning house, but inevitably there'll be more suffering to keep you looking for the solution. And dukkha means things are already unsatisfactory, even if they seem great at the time, because it's all transient, and when they're gone you suffer from the loss.
 
Contemplating dukkha and conditioning the mind to see it in everything is a recommended practice, and as one of the three marks of existence, insight into it is said to be able to result in dispassion, disenchantment, even Awakening.

I think the goal of Buddhism isn't to balance suffering with pleasure, but to be free of both. But there are practices and teachings to help lessen it in the short term. Some are specific to the type of stress, like with the antidotes to the five hindrances, and some are more widely applicable, like letting go and nonresistance. Another thing would be doing good and refraining from bad, to make the karma for future happiness.

I guess I'd say avoid or change the causes, if possible. Otherwise you just have to go through it, and learn ways to deal with it. Trying to get rid of it makes it worse, because it won't go at your command, so you just get more and more frustrated. Ajahn Brahm always says make peace, be kind, be gentle. Sometimes it's possible when you really make peace with an unpleasant feeling, it can actually transform into something nice.
 
But there are suttas that teach about patience, and enduring, tolerating, accepting suffering. Because you can't control what happens, but you can always make it worse, by fighting it and thinking "why me"; why you is because you were born, and it's just the kind of thing that can happen when you live in the world and have a body and mind that are subject to pain.
 
"...it is not possible [to say] with regard to form [etc.], 'Let my form be thus. Let my form not be thus.'" (SN 22.59)
 
"...a person, suffering loss... reflects: 'That's how it is when living together in the world. That's how it is when gaining a personal identity. When there is living in the world, when there is the gaining of a personal identity, these eight worldly conditions spin after the world, and the world spins after these eight worldly conditions: gain, loss, status, disgrace, censure, praise, pleasure, & pain.' Suffering loss of relatives, loss of wealth, or loss through disease, he does not sorrow, grieve, or lament, does not beat his breast or become distraught." (AN 4.192)




The ordinary's suffering could be stopped by just keep on the concentration meditation in every second whole life.
It's the easiest way, such as meditate happiness to see breath every second, etc.

But the insight meditation is after that. It's harder than science, so it's required very strong concentration meditation, as well.



How should lay Buddhists view and make use of dukkha such that it is helpful not only spiritually but also allow them to make meaningful progress in the world?

It's not truth. Most moments in  present life are based on past lives Karma, what we'd done some life in the past and appeared in dead period before we died previous life, each life.
So, if the ordinary imagine to be a billionaire but his present life effecting Karma now is weak. He have to work fucking hard, suffering, selfish and die as a millionaire, if he is very lucky.
But if that ordinary practice past lives recollection and study Abhidhamma, he will see the real Karma process. Then he will let working hard go. He focus on happiness on seeing breath while working instead.
Why?
Because he's seen how Karma work, so he realized that he can't fix his present life easily. He know it's too much hard, suffering, wasting time to be rich now.
But he make his future awesome mind and wisdom instead, meditate it continously, so he is happy every moment from now on by the right meditation. And if he can't attain Nibbana, his meditation will let him be Trillionaire surly in the future. This is better easier and making sense.

Is there a way to strike a balance with stress in our personal and professional lives?

Awesome Causes have ten, Dasa Puññakiriñāvatthu. If you can be happy with them, your breath meditation will be easier. The meditation is the easiest way to depress.

What advice would you give to non-Buddhist friends who are suffering from chronic stress?

Make yourself full happy by the meditation. How you change yourself is how you can change the world.
Why?
Because your friend is your karma's effect. You have that friend because you've done karma to meet him.
So, if your meditation karma is not depress / happy / powerful / skillful enough, you still be effected by the present karma continuously.
It doesn't mean "if you meditation enough he will be the best too" because your friend has his own past Karma as well.
But by this way I can change my parent who occasionally drink to stop them all and begin their meditation.
And I have see people change their related peoples' lives by practice themselves entire my life, so I recommend it.

are you suggesting Ven. Pukkusati death in MN140 is Buddha's fault?

I suggest the way we can practice others successful to be happy. I also said everybody has his own Past Karma, Kammassakata. To explain why you don't understand me is this sentence "What you getting is what you did. Who you helping will be your future friend." Because Pukkussati is dieing no matter he meet the Buddha or not by his own Karma, he did. And the noble one like Buddha is helping him, so he will attain Nibbana like the Buddha. Imagine if it's only Trum or Biden or me who meet Pukkussati instead. So practice ourself is very important in my lifetime experience.
